# Кроссбраузерность в Firefox

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, firefox

Привет всем) Помогите пожалуйста с отображением страницы в Firefox. Сделал все по макету в хроме тестил все норм. Решил глянуть в Firefox и тут нашел проблемы.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: Firefox]

Код блоков такой:

```css
.choice-form {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 860px;
  margin-bottom: 40px;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 0px;
  font-weight: normal;
}

.choice-form input,
.choice-form select,
.choice-form label {
  display: block;
}

.choice-wrapper {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 40px;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 16px;
  margin-right: 16px;
  margin-bottom: 18px;
  vertical-align: top;
}

.choice-form p {
  margin: 0;
  margin-bottom: 6px;
  margin-left: 16px;
}

.choice-form select {
  display: block;
  padding: 10px 32px 10px 14px;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 18px;
  border-radius: 20px;
  border: 0px;
  background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.3);
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  -ms-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}


.choice-wrapper:first-child:after{
  position: absolute;
  top: 40px;
  right: 15px;
  border-top: 4px solid #fff;
  border-right: 4px solid transparent;
  border-left: 4px solid transparent;
  cursor: pointer;
  content: "";
}

.price-controls label {
  display: inline-block;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 18px;
  vertical-align: top;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.price-controls input {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 40px;
  color: inherit;
  vertical-align: top;
  text-align: center;
  border: none;
  background: none;
  outline: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin-bottom: 2px;
}

.price-controls {
  padding-left: 15px;
  margin-right: 15px;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 0px;
}

.price-controls span {
  font-size: 14px;
}

.range-controls {
  position: relative;
  max-width: 218px;
  padding: 17px 15px;
  border-radius: 20px;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);
}

.filter-price__scale {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 100%;
  height: 4px;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
  cursor: pointer;
}

.filter-price__range {
  position: relative;
  margin-left: 20%;
  width: 51%;
  height: inherit;
  background-color: #f8f7f4;
}

.filter-price__toggle {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: #f8f7f4;
  border-radius: 50%;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}

.filter-price__toggle:hover {
  width: 22px;
  height: 22px;
}

.filter-price__toggle-min {
  left: 0;
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
      -ms-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
          transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
}

.filter-price__toggle-max {
  left: 80px;
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
      -ms-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
          transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
}


.radio-wrapper {
  padding: 12px 17px 10px 16px;
  font-size: 0px;
  background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.3);
  border-radius: 20px;
}

.choice-form input[type="radio"] {
  display: none;
}

.radiobtn label {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 20px;
  padding-left: 30px;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 18px;
  vertical-align: top;
  cursor: pointer;
}


.radiobtn label:before {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  left: -1px;
  height: 12px;
  width: 12px;
  border: 3px solid #aabbb1;
  border-radius: 50%;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 1px #fff;
  content: "";
}

.radiobtn label:last-child {
  margin: 0;
}

.choice-wrapper:nth-child(3) {
  margin: 0;
}

.filters {
  padding: 10px 16px 10px 15px;
  font-size: 0px;
  border-radius: 20px;
  background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.3);
}

.filters input {
  display: none;
}

.filters label {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 20px;
  padding-left: 32px;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 18px;
  vertical-align: top;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.filters label:before {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  top: -1px;
  left: 3px;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  border: 1px solid #fff;
  border-radius: 3px;
  content: "";
}

.filters label:after {
    position: absolute;
    top: 5px;
    left: 9px;
    z-index: 1;
    width: 9px;
    height: 5px;
    display: none;
    content: "";
    border: 2px solid #fff;
    border-top-style: none;
    border-right-style: none;
    transform: rotate(-45deg);
}


.filters input[type="checkbox"]:checked + label:after {
  display: block;
}


.filters label:last-child {
  margin: 0;
}

.form-btn {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-bottom: 40px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  vertical-align: top;
  float: right;
}

.choice-form input[type="submit"] {
  padding: 10px 26px;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 18px;
  border: 0px;
  border-radius: 20px;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.19);
  border: 2px solid white;
  cursor: pointer;
  outline: none;
}
```

```html
<form class="choice-form" action="url" method="get">
            <div class="choice-wrapper">
              <p>Сортировка:</p>
              <select name="sort">
                <option value="popular">по популярности</option>
                <option value="cheap">сначала недорогие</option>
                <option value="expensive">сначала дорогие</option>
                <option value="fat">по жирности</option>
              </select>
            </div>
            <div class="choice-wrapper filter-range">
              <div class="price-controls">
                <span>Цена:</span>
                <label class="min-price"> <input type="text" name="min-price" value="100"></label>
                <span class="txt-rub">руб&nbsp; </span>
                <span> – </span>
                <label class="max-price"><input type="text" name="max-price" value="500"></label>
                <span class="txt-rub">руб</span>
              </div>
              <div class="range-controls">
                <div class="filter-price__scale">
                    <div class="filter-price__range" style="margin-left: 20%; width: 41%">
                      <div class="filter-price__toggle filter-price__toggle-min"></div>
                      <div class="filter-price__toggle filter-price__toggle-max"></div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            <div class="choice-wrapper radiobtn">
              <p>Жирность:</p>
              <div class="radio-wrapper">
                <input type="radio" name="fat" value="zero" id="zero">
                <label for="zero">0%</label>
                <input type="radio" name="fat" value="ten" id="ten" checked>
                <label for="ten">до 10%</label>
                <input type="radio" name="fat" value="thirty" id="thirty">
                <label for="thirty">до 30%</label>
                <input type="radio" name="fat" value="more-thirty" id="more-thirty">
                <label for="more-thirty">выше 30%</label>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="choice-wrapper">
              <p>Наполнители:</p>
              <div class="filters">
                <input type="checkbox" name="chocolate" id="chocolate" checked>
                <label for="chocolate">шоколадные</label>
                <input type="checkbox" name="sugar" id="sugar" checked>
                <label for="sugar">сахарные присыпки</label>
                <input type="checkbox" name="fruits" id=fruits>
                <label for="fruits">фрукты</label>
                <input type="checkbox" name="syrup" id="syrup">
                <label for="syrup">сиропы</label>
                <input type="checkbox" name="jam" id="jam">
                <label for="jam">джемы</label>
              </div>
            </div>
            <input class="form-btn" type="submit" value="Применить">
          </form>
```

Comment: Очень похоже на разный масштаб.

Answer (score 1):

Примените указание размеров в стилях в % а не в пикселях. **[Информация Moz](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Mozilla_Extensions)**

Comment: Как вообще ответ связан со ссылкой??